# WSO2 API Manager with BAM issue

Tags: wso2

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2, SP1 box set up with the latest versions of WSO2 API Manager and Business Activity Manager (BAM).  I've followed the documentation (starting over several times) for configuring each.  In API Manager, I've enabled APIUsageTracking (xpath=APIManager/APIUsageTracking/Enabled), left the ThriftPort set at 7612, and have set up the WSO2AM_STATS_DB data source in the master-datasources.xml file for both API Manager and BAM.  I've set the Server/Ports/Offset value in carbon.xml in API Manager to 1, per the documentation.  When I try to start the server, however, I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR - APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher Error initializing APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.exception.AgentException: Cannot borrow client for TCP,localhost:7612,TCP,localhost:7712

Any thought on what I might be missing?

Thanks in advance!  Please let me know if I can provide any extra information.  I'm new to WSO2, so I won't feel insulted if I'm missing something stupid obvious.  :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, looks like my issue was actually in my environment variables.  Do NOT declare CARBON_HOME; let the servers figure that out for itself.

Answer (score 0):

Could you also please verify whether BAM server has been started successfully.  I noticed that there was some issues when starting WSO2 BAM in windows environment. [1]

[1]http://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM200/FAQ#FAQ-Igetanexceptionstating- ERRORorgapachehadoophiveqlexecExecDriver-JobSubmissionfailedwithexceptionjavaioIOExceptionCannotrunprogramchmodCreateProcesserror2Thesystemcannotfindthefilespecified javaioIOExceptionCannotrunprogramchmodCreateProcesserror2Thes

Comment: That was the problem.  Because I'd specified CARBON_HOME in the environment variables, I could start up AM, but not BAM, or visa-versa, but not both.  As soon as I removed the CARBON_HOME environment variable, it started working correctly.  Thanks!